# problems with vertical line spacing when using enumitem and newtcbox for labeling

Tags: enumitem

I want to avoid that the vertical separation between the first two lines of the itemize paragraph is bigger than the rest when the label is written with a box as it happens in this example:

[image]

This is the code that produces that output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{colback=blue!10,colframe=blue!30,tcbox raise base, #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\mybox{\arabic*}]
  \item Primer ítem en la lista, una línea más larga para demostrar el espaciado entre las líneas del párrafo. Primer ítem en la lista, una línea más larga para demostrar el espaciado entre las líneas del párrafo. Primer ítem en la lista, una línea más larga para demostrar el espaciado entre las líneas del párrafo.
  \item Segundo ítem en la lista.
  \item Tercer ítem en la lista.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to `LaTeX`-- can we please see the code which produces this output

Comment: Thanks! I added the LaTeX code.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to shrink the vertical bounding box of the `tcolorbox` using `enlarge top by` and `enlarge bottom by`. Since by default 3.5 mm are added to its content (2 mm for `top`/`bottom`, 1 mm for `boxsep` and 0.5 mm for `boxrule`), use:

```tex
\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{%
  enlarge top by=-3.5mm, enlarge bottom by=-3.5mm,
  colback=blue!10,colframe=blue!30,tcbox raise base, #1}
```

Item separation should then be enlarged to avoid box overlapping. Try:

```tex
\begin{enumerate}[label=\mybox{\arabic*}, itemsep=5mm plus 0.5em]
```

Full code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{%
  enlarge top by=-3.5mm, enlarge bottom by=-3.5mm,
  colback=blue!10,colframe=blue!30,tcbox raise base, #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\mybox{\arabic*}, itemsep=5mm plus 0.5em]
  \item Primer ítem en la lista, una línea más larga para demostrar el espaciado entre las líneas del párrafo. Primer ítem en la lista, una línea más larga para demostrar el espaciado entre las líneas del párrafo. Primer ítem en la lista, una línea más larga para demostrar el espaciado entre las líneas del párrafo.
  \item Segundo ítem en la lista.
  \item Tercer ítem en la lista.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: List with tcolorbox as label]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! You are much more helpful than chatGPT. 

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution with `\tikz` and `tabularray`.

- In `Tikz`, I creates a counter style using the default values ​​of `tcbox`

\tikzset{
counter/.style=
{
draw=blue!30,
fill=blue!10,
inner xsep=4.0 mm,
inner ysep=2.0 mm,
rounded corners=1mm,
}
}

- In `tabularray`, I use the counter library (p.48 in the documentation)

  ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{tabularray}
   \UseTblrLibrary{counter}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \newcounter{mycnta}
   \newcommand{\mycnta}{\stepcounter{mycnta}\arabic{mycnta}}
   %
   \tikzset{
       counter/.style=
       {
           draw=blue!30,
           fill=blue!10,
           inner xsep=4.0 mm,
           inner ysep=2.0 mm,
           rounded corners=1mm,
       }
       }
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tblr}{
       colspec={Q[l,wd=2.5em] X},
       column{1} = {cmd=\tikz[baseline] {\node[counter]{\mycnta .};}}
   }
   & Primer ítem en la lista, una línea más larga para demostrar el espaciado entre las líneas del párrafo. Primer ítem en la lista, una línea más larga para demostrar el espaciado entre las líneas del párrafo. Primer ítem en la lista, una línea más larga para demostrar el espaciado entre las líneas del párrafo.\\
   &Segundo ítem en la lista.\\
   & Tercer ítem en la lista.
   \end{tblr}
   \end{document}
  ```

[image]